# How to use <form> action to redirect to method in routing using LUMEN

Tags: php, lumen

Lumen does not use Collective/html. When I try to use form action : 

I got error ** **Call to undefined function action()** 
How can I send form to specific method in my route ?

I have controller and store method.
I have routing to my controller
I have form and want to point to specific method

My form :

```php
<form action="{{ action('LicensesController@store') }}" method='POST'>
```

but i got error **Call to undefined function action()**

My controller's method :

```php
    // saving to database
    public function store(Request $request){
    }
```

My routing : 
on page /licenses/create I have form and want to send it to @store method (where I will save it to database

```php
Route::get('/licenses', 'LicensesController@index');
Route::post('/licenses', 'LicensesController@store');
Route::get('/licenses/create', 'LicensesController@create');
Route::get('/licenses/{licence}', 'LicensesController@show');
```

How can I send form to specific method in my route using LUMEN (where a lot of Laravel's  function does not work)

I can use

```php
<form action="/licenses" method='POST'>
```

and it works , as routing will fire store method but I think there is more proper way , more eloquent , and you can help me find it